# How can I get my function to execute with a tuple of strings?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm pretty new to python and just getting the hang of it so forgive me if this isn't the most precise explanation. I was given a tuple of strings with the name countries

```
countries = ('Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'Andorra', 'Angola', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Argentina', 'Armenia', 'Australia',
             'Austria', 'Azerbaijan', 'Bahamas', 'Bahrain', 'Bangladesh', 'Barbados', 'Belarus', 'Belgium', 'Belize', 'Benin',
             'Bhutan', 'Bolivia', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'Botswana', 'Brazil', 'Brunei', 'Bulgaria', 'Burkina Faso', 'Burundi',
             'Cambodia', 'Cameroon', 'Canada', 'Cape Verde', 'Central African Republic', 'Chad', 'Chile', 'China', 'Colombia', 'Comoros',
             'Congo, Democratic Republic of the', 'Congo, Republic of the', 'Costa Rica', "CÃ´te d'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)", 'Croatia', 'Cuba',
             'Cyprus', 'Czech Republic (Czechia)', 'Denmark', 'Djibouti', 'Dominica', 'Dominican Republic', 'East Timor', 'Ecuador', 'Egypt',
             'El Salvador', 'England', 'Equatorial Guinea', 'Eritrea', 'Estonia', 'Eswatini (Swaziland)', 'Ethiopia', 'Federated States of Micronesia',
             'Fiji', 'Finland', 'France', 'Gabon', 'Gambia', 'Georgia', 'Germany', 'Ghana', 'Greece', 'Grenada', 'Guatemala', 'Guinea', 'Guinea-Bissau',
             'Guyana', 'Haiti', 'Honduras', 'Hungary', 'Iceland', 'India', 'Indonesia', 'Iran', 'Iraq', 'Ireland', 'Israel', 'Italy', 'Jamaica', 'Japan',
             'Jordan', 'Kazakhstan', 'Kenya', 'Kiribati', 'Kosovo', 'Kuwait', 'Kyrgyzstan', 'Laos', 'Latvia', 'Lebanon', 'Lesotho', 'Liberia', 'Libya',
             'Liechtenstein', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Madagascar', 'Malawi', 'Malaysia', 'Maldives', 'Mali', 'Malta', 'Marshall Islands', 'Mauritania',
             'Mauritius', 'Mexico', 'Moldova', 'Monaco', 'Mongolia', 'Montenegro', 'Morocco', 'Mozambique', 'Myanmar (Burma)', 'Namibia', 'Nauru', 'Nepal',
             'Netherlands', 'New Zealand', 'Nicaragua', 'Niger', 'Nigeria', 'North Korea', 'North Macedonia (Macedonia)', 'Northern Ireland', 'Norway', 'Oman',
             'Pakistan', 'Palau', 'Panama', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Paraguay', 'Peru', 'Philippines', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Qatar', 'Romania', 'Russia', 'Rwanda',
             'Saint Kitts and Nevis', 'Saint Lucia', 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines', 'Samoa', 'San Marino', 'Sao Tome and Principe', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Scotland',
             'Senegal', 'Serbia', 'Seychelles', 'Sierra Leone', 'Singapore', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Solomon Islands', 'Somalia', 'South Africa', 'South Korea',
             'South Sudan', 'Spain', 'Sri Lanka', 'Sudan', 'Suriname', 'Sweden', 'Switzerland', 'Syria', 'Taiwan', 'Tajikistan', 'Tanzania', 'Thailand', 'Togo',
             'Tonga', 'Trinidad and Tobago', 'Tunisia', 'Turkey', 'Turkmenistan', 'Tuvalu', 'Uganda', 'Ukraine', 'United Arab Emirates', 'United Kingdom', 'United States',
             'Uruguay', 'Uzbekistan', 'Vanuatu', 'Vatican City', 'Venezuela', 'Vietnam', 'Wales', 'Yemen', 'Zambia', 'Zimbabwe')
```

I need to create two functions

1. how_many_countries
2. get_name_of_longest_country

These are my code which gave me the output I wanted before I called a function.

```
print("countries", len(countries))



longest_country = max(countries, key=len)
    print(longest_country)
```

However, when I added

```
def how_many_countries():

    total = countries
    print("countries", len(countries))
```

and...

```
def get_name_of_longest_country():

    longest_country = max(countries, key=len)
    print(longest_country)
```

it doesn't show me anything in my terminal, just process finished with exit code 0. I'm not supposed to change the function names or edit anything from the tuple of strings given. I get the output I want without adding a function but when I do it's not showing anything. What am I missing in this case?

I'm using Python 3. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: how did you call your function? Seems like there is no problem with your function

Answer (score 1):

```
how_many_countries()
get_name_of_longest_country()
```

By calling your function as above, you should receive the output. nothing is wrong..

output:

```
countries 200
Congo, Democratic Republic of the
```

Full code should look like below:

```
countries = ('Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'Andorra', 'Angola', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Argentina', 'Armenia', 'Australia', 'Austria', 'Azerbaijan', 'Bahamas', 'Bahrain', 'Bangladesh', 'Barbados', 'Belarus', 'Belgium', 'Belize', 'Benin', 'Bhutan', 'Bolivia', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'Botswana', 'Brazil', 'Brunei', 'Bulgaria', 'Burkina Faso', 'Burundi', 'Cambodia', 'Cameroon', 'Canada', 'Cape Verde', 'Central African Republic', 'Chad', 'Chile', 'China', 'Colombia', 'Comoros', 'Congo, Democratic Republic of the', 'Congo, Republic of the', 'Costa Rica', "CÃ´te d'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)", 'Croatia', 'Cuba', 'Cyprus', 'Czech Republic (Czechia)', 'Denmark', 'Djibouti', 'Dominica', 'Dominican Republic', 'East Timor', 'Ecuador', 'Egypt', 'El Salvador', 'England', 'Equatorial Guinea', 'Eritrea', 'Estonia', 'Eswatini (Swaziland)', 'Ethiopia', 'Federated States of Micronesia', 'Fiji', 'Finland', 'France', 'Gabon', 'Gambia', 'Georgia', 'Germany', 'Ghana', 'Greece', 'Grenada', 'Guatemala', 'Guinea', 'Guinea-Bissau', 'Guyana', 'Haiti', 'Honduras', 'Hungary', 'Iceland', 'India', 'Indonesia', 'Iran', 'Iraq', 'Ireland', 'Israel', 'Italy', 'Jamaica', 'Japan', 'Jordan', 'Kazakhstan', 'Kenya', 'Kiribati', 'Kosovo', 'Kuwait', 'Kyrgyzstan', 'Laos', 'Latvia', 'Lebanon', 'Lesotho', 'Liberia', 'Libya', 'Liechtenstein', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Madagascar', 'Malawi', 'Malaysia', 'Maldives', 'Mali', 'Malta', 'Marshall Islands', 'Mauritania', 'Mauritius', 'Mexico', 'Moldova', 'Monaco', 'Mongolia', 'Montenegro', 'Morocco', 'Mozambique', 'Myanmar (Burma)', 'Namibia', 'Nauru', 'Nepal', 'Netherlands', 'New Zealand', 'Nicaragua', 'Niger', 'Nigeria', 'North Korea', 'North Macedonia (Macedonia)', 'Northern Ireland', 'Norway', 'Oman', 'Pakistan', 'Palau', 'Panama', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Paraguay', 'Peru', 'Philippines', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Qatar', 'Romania', 'Russia', 'Rwanda', 'Saint Kitts and Nevis', 'Saint Lucia', 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines', 'Samoa', 'San Marino', 'Sao Tome and Principe', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Scotland', 'Senegal', 'Serbia', 'Seychelles', 'Sierra Leone', 'Singapore', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Solomon Islands', 'Somalia', 'South Africa', 'South Korea', 'South Sudan', 'Spain', 'Sri Lanka', 'Sudan', 'Suriname', 'Sweden', 'Switzerland', 'Syria', 'Taiwan', 'Tajikistan', 'Tanzania', 'Thailand', 'Togo', 'Tonga', 'Trinidad and Tobago', 'Tunisia', 'Turkey', 'Turkmenistan', 'Tuvalu', 'Uganda', 'Ukraine', 'United Arab Emirates', 'United Kingdom', 'United States', 'Uruguay', 'Uzbekistan', 'Vanuatu', 'Vatican City', 'Venezuela', 'Vietnam', 'Wales', 'Yemen', 'Zambia', 'Zimbabwe')

def how_many_countries():
    total = countries
    print("countries", len(countries))

def get_name_of_longest_country():
    longest_country = max(countries, key=len)
    print(longest_country)

how_many_countries()
get_name_of_longest_country()
```

Comment: unless your code editor isn't able to show you an output.. That you gotta figure out.

Comment: Without the function actually I get the output I wanted. When I added it this time I'm getting a NameError: 'how_many_countries' is not defined.... I'm using PyCharm.

Comment: did you ensure that your functions are added above of the function call? The sequence must be correct. Define functions first, then call the functions below.

Comment: you may refer to the edits, full code should look something like this

Comment: I finally got it to work, I had other 6 functions and these ones are in the wrong sequence. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `if __name__ == "__main__":` while running python file from terminal with syntax `python YOURFILENAME.py` command?

I have to ask like this since I am new to STACKOVERFLOW and do not have privileges to comment and ask yet :(

So please comment down on this answer and tell me your answer in "Yes" or "No" so that I can help you accordingly

Comment: Hey, thank you for taking the time to take a look at this. I finally got this to work with Hj Sin's help but I appreciate your input too. I basically had 8 functions in total and my sequence was wrong on these 2.